# Test Recipe: How to test a ruby gem with rails dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am developing a ruby gem which provides some methods that can be mixed into a ActiveRecord model, similar to e.g. acts_as_taggable.

My question is: How do I write e.g. unit tests for my code without having a rails app? My model relies e.g. on an existing database / connection that rails establishes. If there is no connection, the test execution fails.

I also need to copy some files from my gem directory to the rails app using e.g. RAILS_ROOT to detect the rails app dir. Environment variables are also not available.

What would be your approach? Can a rails app somehow be "simulated" during test runs?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same question these days: 
[Rspec, test Gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211971/rspec-test-gems)

You'd see interesting resources in my own answer.

I ended up creating a rails app in the test directory of my gem. In the gem file of my app, I've referenced my gem in development with it's relative path.

In a few words: I test the gem through the app.

Have a look at: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

I've a dummy Rails app with all Rspec tests.

Comment: Thanks! I found this resources in the meantime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086578/proper-way-of-testing-gems, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722918/testing-ruby-gems-under-rails. Both give some solutions but didn´t provide the one I am looking for. Creating an application inside the test folder is one, but feels (IMO) like a bit of overload ;-)